# webpack создает версия 10.0.0 создает main.js вместо bundle.js

Tags: webpack

Коллеги, у меня проблема.
Создал функцию
// Функция возвращает имя файла с хешем или без в зависимости от режима работы

```
const filename = ext => isDev ? 'bundle.${ext}' : 'bundle.[hash].${ext}'
```

Добавляю ее в 1 место:

```
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: filename('js'),
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
```

Все работает нормально, НО в dist появляется main.js, а не bundle.js, Sorry создается то bundle.${ext} - может что-то в функции не так?
правда и main.js в какой-то момент тоже создается.

Добавляю ее в plugins вот так

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: filename('scss')
}),
```

получаю ошибку:
[webpack-cli] Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename bundle.${ext} (chunks main and main)

Пример взят от Владилена Минина 2020 года. Что-то сейчас изменилось видимо....
На английской версии сайта мне посоветовали в конец webpack.config.js добавить такой код:

```
if (process.env.BABEL_ENV === 'test') {
  module.exports.output.filename = '[name].[hash:8].js'
}
```

Но этот код никак не учитывает мой scss в pluguns, а из-за пределов module.exports webpack не видит plugins, ну а внутри, естественно, не работает if
До добавления функции все работало и создавался bundle.js и bundle.scss. Функция как раз и создавалась для добавления или не добавления hash к именам bundle, а вместо этого создается main.js или конфликт со ссылкой на этот main (chunks main and main)

На всякий случай вот полный текст моего webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebPackPligin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebPackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const isProd = process.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const isDev  = !isProd

// Функция возвращает имя файла с хешем или без в зависимости от режима работы
const filename = ext => isDev ? 'bundle.${ext}' : 'bundle.[hash].${ext}'

console.log('is Prod', isProd)
console.log('is Dev', isDev)

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        filename: filename('js'),
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
            '@core': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/core')
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HTMLWebPackPligin({
            template: "index.html",
            minify: {
                removeComments: isProd,
                collapseWhitespace: isProd
            }
        }),
        new CopyWebPackPlugin(
            {
                patterns: [
                    {
                      from: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/favicon.ico'),
                      to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') }
                ],
            }
        ),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: filename('scss')
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                        },
                },
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Буду очень признателен за ответ. Не могу продвинуться дальше.

Answer (score 1):

Все нашел ошибку в функции - увы, я использовал прямые кавычки вместо  косых ``. С косыми все работает правильно.

Причина была в неправильных кавычках и webpack создавал `Bundel.${ext}` - файлы в любом режиме, а вот косыми кавычками я получаю Bunle.js и Bundle.scss, или их же с хешем.
Низкий поклон создателю JavaScript за '' и `` - это, видимо, для развития внимательности сделано.